# LibreOffice -convert-to pdf mode can't convert documents with user-defined functions

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I have LibreOffice Calc document with some user-defined functions in Basic used to calculate values in cells. I can open this document in GUI and export it to PDF without problems. but when I use *soffice.exe -headless -convert-to pdf filename* command line call all user-defined functions are not found so I have broken document. I tried also convertor working with background LibreOffice instance through UNO API - with the same result.

Is this possible to switch on user-defined functions and have well-converted PDF by command line or UNO interface? Example of [document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YWkj8deTNITGVEYUZSaXluUkU/edit?usp=sharing), [cli conversion result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YWkj8deTNIT1RGblVBbjh4N2M/edit?usp=sharing) and [desired result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YWkj8deTNIc2NTaXh3dG1ZUlk/edit?usp=sharing).

UPD: LibreOffice Windows version 4.2.4.2 both Portable and Standard.

Comment: Please update with the version of _soffice_. I try to open your file with _libreoffice_ for linux.  Of course, as I open inside _calc_, I have  the same situation of the corrupted _pdf_, because I don't have your path and files... so a clue maybe the filter is not able to find those path too... [Here you should find all the filters](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/filter/source/config/fragments/filters) that you can use. As a workaround try to save in _xls_ and to use one of the _xls filter_

Comment: I check it against LibreOffice for Linux and document opened fine (as minimum here must be "Just a text" text) but it need to enable macros execution in Tools - Option - LibreOffice - Security - Macro Security. Please check this setting. Document provided is self-contained and has no external dependencies. Conversion result the same as in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Libreoffice uses (Acrobat) JavaScript for the user defined functions, you have no chance to properly convert them to Acrobat JavaScript.

That means, if you have calculations in your spreadsheet, you do best to not bother about getting them from the spreadsheet to the PDF, but simply recreate them in (Acrobat) JavaScript.

Comment: It seems my question is not clear enough. I don't need to convert user defined functions to PDF, I want to have the same result from command line conversion as from GUI.

Comment: It could be that I did not completely get what you want to accomplish. Do I therefore understand correctly that you do not want to transform the spreadsheet to a smart PDF, but to create a simple (not smart) PDF document of a filled spreadsheet, where you need the results of the calculations? If so, my suspicion is that the error happens even before the document is converted to PDF.

Comment: Yes, I need simple PDF with results of calculations. I can do it in GUI using _File_ - _Export to PDF_ without any problem, but I need to do this automatically, using command line or UNO API.
Yes, here is error before converting because of disables macroses in automatic mode. So question is: how to enable macroses when loading document in -convert-to mode or UNO request.